# unable to open software center and updatemanager

Tags: apt, software-center

I deleted `opt.conf.d folder` in `/etc/apt` and I copied a new one from live dvd after this my software center, update manager, are not able to open.

When I open software center it is giving me an error message.

```
SystemError: E:Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - opendir (13: Permission denied)
```

but I am able to open synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner of the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory to root and then try to open software center,

```
sudo chown root /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
```

And also change owner of all the files inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory to `root`.